# Google yolo one tab signup plugin avilable in wordpress?

Tags: css, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Can you please tell me wordpress has Google yolo one tab signup plugin?

Answer (score 2):

No. Google One *Tap* was shut down, and [no longer exists](https://developers.google.com/identity/one-tap/web/).

Comment: It does exist. Maybe it was shut down for some time, but now it's back.